How would I "move" X Axis Mirror point to multiple locations for an animated scene?
Just to clarify, everything is working as intended. The correct bones are being mirrored, they're moving with the correct transformations, etc., etc. The X Mirror feature hinges on a little orange point connected to the rig, which makes sense as that's how it mirrors the armature when not perfectly on the X Axis. My issue is that as I'm animating the scene, the model that I'm animating is moving around, but the center point used as reference for the X Mirror feature doesn't move, so the armature will continue to mirror from that location instead of where the rest of the model actually moved to. I haven't been able to find someone else asking this question and every solution I'm personally thinking of is incredibly tedious as the only way I've been able to move that reference point is to exit Pose Mode and move the entire rig.



That's my frustration, that everything is working as intended, but I can't find a way to move the X Mirror reference location, which causes my model to stretch across until it's past the point again. Is there a way to move the reference point in Pose Mode, or to have the point move with, say, a central body bone?


I made a discovery that solved the issue. That orange point isn't just a reference location for X Mirror, it's probably the armature's origin point as a whole, and my problem happened because the bones that I wanted to mirror weren't parented to any other bone, so they were using the origin point as a reference for what the "middle" was, no matter where the rig moved during animation.
Parenting the bones I wanted to mirror to a root bone of the armature fixed it and they now use that root as the "middle", which is exactly what I wanted since I can move that bone instead of the whole rig in Object Mode.
